# Add text in front of field in database query result set

Tags: database, firebird

I am running a database query and would like to prepend the ID field with the letters "LG".  A result would be something "LG23493" (where the ID is 23493).  I know I can probably do this afterwards with some script, but I want to do this within the actual query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [concatenation operator in Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-concat.html) is `||`, so you would want something like `'LG'||id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concatenation `CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( 'LG', id ) AS id ,
    ...
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I am doing this with a Firebird database.. this works with mysql i would imagine only.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat('LG', id) from mytable
```